# How to convert unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops(nextprops) to useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I am new to ReactJS. I want to convert the class components into functional components.
Please help.

I need help in converting **unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops(nextprops) to useEffect**

```
UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.props.getDirects(this.state.myDirects);
  }

 const getDirects = directs => {
   setMyDirects(directs || []);
  };
```

Comment: you can do like this. -> `useEffect(()=>{
    props.getDirects(myDirects)
  }, [props])`

Answer (score 0):

```js
/*
UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  this.props.getDirects(this.state.myDirects);
}
*/

function yourComp({ getDirects }){
  const [myDirects, setMyDirects] = React.useState();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    getDirects(myDirects);
  }, [getDirects, myDirects]);

  return(...);
}
```